# Video doesn't work well in skype

Tags: webcam, skype

My built in cam works fine in cheese. However in skype it doesn't show me at all. In test skype show myself view doesn't work either. How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I hate to say this, but get used to it. While most things work well, or well enough, a few software companies don't care enough about linux to test extensively -- or at least, not as extensively as in other OSses. Skype is one of these. Also, Microsoft recently bought Skype, so it won't be getting any less buggy.

Comment: Whether skype or microsoft are a pain is irrelevant ..this person actually needs an answer or we lose 'em

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer depends on your webcam not just because you have Linux!

Maybe you have a webcam that lots of people have had problems with in both Linux and Windows

First perhaps you could help us to understand more if you let us know what make of webcam you have

Please open a terminal and type 
lspci

Then paste the results back here

It might be that you have a logitech webcam  ( they are a pain BUT fixable)

IF you have a look at this page you may get some help

[How to fix webcam problems in Skype](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/05/how-to-fix-webcam-problem-in-skype.html)

If you are still around ...let us know how you get on :)

Answer (score 0):

After fighting with skype, getting just banality results that finishes in the correct usage of skype at the time that the up to 3 days setup is needed to work properly, just to find skype to become useless for videoconferencing simply after a reboot I stopped using skype for videoconferencing. Which I don't suggest you to but if you are in need to have a videoconference soon you may be interested on several Websites Flash Player based alternatives, which includes but not limits to those mentioned in this list:

http://www.moreofit.com/similar-to/www.tokbox.com/Top_10_Sites_Like_Tokbox/

Of which I have successfully tested the MeBeam Video Chat (http://www.mebeam.com), Boostcam (http://www.boostcam.com) and Ubiqq (http://www.ubiqq.com) which is also my favorite.

If you experience an issue with your Flash Player that won't reach your webcam, I suggest you take a look at this answer: [Webcam not detected by Flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53028/webcam-not-detected-by-flash/56324#56324) which also offers a few alternatives for that issue.

As I said in the beginning of this answer, this won't fit your skype issue but will allow you to have a yet decent videoconference, fast and without need to face lots of procedures in order to try forcing skype to do what it can't for now.

I am following your question closely in order to see if somebody else come and drops a good answer for this issue, which I have been facing since 9.04 and is not yet fully supported and may be it won't as fast as we'd like.

Good luck!