# logitec webcam for notebooks deluxe

Tags: webcam

Im using a logitec webcam for notebooks deluxe, I want to know why on some sites, I cannot go cam to cam with other host, they don't see or hear me. I haven't tried skype, but cam works fine with windows 7, but i rather use ubuntu, much faster video with webcam.
Can someone please help me, does it work for all sites or not??

Answer (score 1):

Sites using flash player as a base will will report some issues or bad experiences (compared with MS Based Systems).

I would suggest you to take a look at the solutions suggested on the answers to the list of questions at the end of this, in order to get a clue on where to start and probably try it yourself, which may improve your experience using your webcam in certain sites.

## https://askubuntu.com/questions/53495/flash-crashes-on-enabling-webcam

and

## [Webcam not detected by Flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53028/webcam-not-detected-by-flash)

Posted here for your convenience:

> In my experience with this issue, Flash Player is experiencing some
>   kind of problem to handle several video sources (which may not be your
>   case). In my computer I have several video sources, and somehow it
>   seems that Flash Player can reach the TV Tuner but is having problems
>   to acquire images from the USB devices.
>
> In order to solve this problem I have tried two tricks that I share to
>   you not as a solution for your issue but as an alternative. The usage
>   of the FlashCam Project or the Webcam Studio. Both them will drop a
>   virtual device into your Flash Player device's list which will be easy
>   handled.
>
> In this answer:
>   https://askubuntu.com/questions/53495/flash-crashes-on-enabling-webcam/53615#53615
>   I have previously documented this situation and I hope you find it
>   useful, pasted here for your convenience:
>
> > Based on my personal experience when using the Ultimate Edition
> >     DistroPlayer, fully documented here:
> >     http://forumubuntusoftware.info/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=4998&start=0 ,
> >     and information that can be reached here:
> >     https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-204, you can use [**The
> >     Flashcam
> >     Project**](http://www.swift-tools.net/Flashcam/) in order to gain access to your webcam via Flash
> >     Player.
> >
> > I have tried this both in Firefox and Chromium/Google-Chrome and it
> >     works like a charm but I continue experiencing some issues with the
> >     stability of the Flash Player when it tries to gain access to my TV
> >     Tuner instead of the Webcam itself.
> >
> > Another temporal solution that I find useful is the usage of the
> >     [**WebCam Studio for GNU/Linux**](http://www.ws4gl.org/), which will drop a bridge
> >     between
> >     your physical webcam and a virtual webcam that can be seen and
> >     managed
> >     by Flash Player.
> >
> > However, you may experience some issues when using both these tools,
> >     anyway it's worth than expecting Flash Player to do what it seems it
> >     can't.
> >
> > Give it a try, and please inform how do you manage this issue. I am
> >     yet interested on having the experiences of other people in order to
> >     fix my TVTuner/Webcam crashing issue.
> >
> > Good luck!

However, these are my answers but answers from other people may give you an idea.

Good luck!